# HTMLでファイルの名前によって画像ファイルが表示されない

Tags: html, jsp

jsp servletで画像ファイルをアップロードすることを作っています。
servletとFTPを利用してファイルをアップロードすることは出来ました。

問題はhtmlで表示されるファイルと表示されないファイルがあります。
以下の画像の通り、`test.jpg` と `test1.jpg` を例えば以下のコードで表現すると、`test1.jpg`が表示されません。他の人にUTF-8を指定していないから言われましたけど
全部正常的に終わりました。どこが問題なのか分かりません。
ぜひ手伝ってくれましたらありがとうございます！！

```
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body> 
<%
        //実際のコードじゃなくて簡単な例のコードです
        UserDAO userProcess = new UserDAO();
        Writer writer = userProcess.viewLookup(boardID);
        String conTentFileName = writer.getFileName();
%>

       <img src="./fileIndex/<%=conTentFileName %>">
</body>
</html>
```

[image: ファイルは正常的にアップロード出来ました]

[image: test.jpgファイルはよく見えます。]

[image: test.jpgファイルはよく見えますけどtest1.jpgファイルは写真の通りよく見えません。。]

Comment: それぞれの画面を右クリックし、ソース（HTML）を表示して、`<img src="./fileIndex/・・・`の部分（パス）がどのようになっているか確認してみて下さい。そして、そのパスに画像ファイルが存在するか確認して下さい。

Comment: 返事ありがとうございます。こへいさんが言ってくれた通りブラウザで確認してみましたが。。test.jpg意外は表象されませんです。確かパスの問題だと思って絶対パスですりゃ出来ました。しかしなぜ相対パスでtest.jpg意外の他のファイルは出来ないのかはまだ分かりません。。